Logging into LookerStudio report embedded in webpage using a google service account
We need to programmatically embed a few looker studio reports in our Webpage/app for different users to see. But these users may not have a google login when they login to our app. So we thought of maintaining a common service account that's not exposed to the users, but we will use this account to login to looker and show the report seamlessly. Went through some documentation in LookerStudio help but not clear how to achieve this. Is this possible? if not, what is a good way to achieve this?
We did see this doc about their API, but wasn't sure if this is what we need.
https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/integrate/api

The "Embed edition" of Looker core may suit your requirements, using Signed Embedding.

Signed embedding is a way to present private embedded Looks, visualizations, Explores, dashboards, or LookML dashboards to your users without requiring them to have a separate Looker login. Instead, users will be authenticated through your own application.
Signed embedding works by creating a special Looker URL that you will use in an iframe. The URL contains the information you want to share, the ID of the user in your system, and the permissions that you want the user to have. You'll then sign the URL with a secret key provided by Looker.

